# creating zip without directory when unzip only files will come

Tags: 14.04, zip

I  want to zip two file, I have try this

```
cd xyz
ls
   a.php
   b.php

zip -r zipped_dir.zip *
```

when i unzip zipped_dir then it give a folder

```
zipped_dir
 -> a.php
 -> b.php
```

but i don't want a folder i just want when i unzip this it  give me files

```
a.php
b.php
```

not in folder

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: done please check question

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) and thus off-topic, also note your system is very behind on upgrades; as 14.05.6 was officially released 7-Mar-2019 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/08/ubuntu-14-04-6-lts-released/ 
 http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/ ) so your system hasn't had all patches applied since at latest that date.  You're using an un-patched and now EOL release of Ubuntu so please consider that , but note you're off-topic here now.